# Ошибка getComputedStyle в Swiper JS

Tags: javascript

возникла непонятка при инициализации слайдера от SwiperJS возникает такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да по ошибке понятно что якобы я передаю не корректный элемент, но все немного сложнее, я начал капаться что не так и решил посмотреть как в сам модуль передаётся этот элемент, в тайпингах это

```
container: CSSSelector | HTMLElement
```

Думаю ладно, открою DevTools и попробуем там получить стили этого DOM узла

Пишу `window.getComputesStyle('.slider')` и точно такая же ошибка, логично, ведь этот метод принимает тип `Element` но не как не `CSSSelector | HTMLElement` в случае с Swiper`ом, и если сделать так

```
const elem = document.querySelector('.slider');
window.getComputesStyle(elem)
```

Все чудесно, но если передать эту переменную в SwiperJS то все равно будет такая ошибка, господа, подскажите!

Comment: const elem = document.querySelector('slide'); - slide  это  тег такой? если класс  то точка должна быть. смотри правильность селектора.

Comment: Прошу прощения, там должна быть точка, просто писал в ручную тут и упустил ее(Поправленно спасибо что увидели) в самом коде все окей с этим

Comment: так  а  console.log(elem)  что  показывает?

Comment: Выводит элемент в консоль